# Django displaying related objects

Tags: django, django-views

I have models for ProjectNotes and for ProjectNotesComments. ProjectNotesComments have a foreign key that is the ProjectNotes id. I am able to save comments on notes. I can see them in the admin panel.

However I have not been able to figure out how to display the comments on the notes.

Here are the models:

```
class ProjectNotes(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = tinymce_models.HTMLField()
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, default=0, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='notes')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class ProjectNoteComments(models.Model):
    body = tinymce_models.HTMLField()
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    projectnote = models.ForeignKey(ProjectNotes, default=0, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
```

Here is the view:

```
class ProjectNotesDetailView(DetailView):
    model = ProjectNotes
    id = ProjectNotes.objects.only('id')
    template_name = 'company_accounts/project_note_detail.html'
    comments = ProjectNotes.comments
```

This is the template I am currently using to test getting the comments to display:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="section-container container">
  <div class="project-entry">
    <h2>{{ projectnotes.title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ projectnotes.body | safe }}</p>
  </div>
  <div>
</div>
{% for comment in comments %}
        <div class="comments" style="padding: 10px;">
          <p class="font-weight-bold">
            {{ comment.body | linebreaks }}
            
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
  
  <h2><a href="{% url 'add_project_note_comment' projectnotes.pk %}">add note</a></h2>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this actually works: `comments = ProjectNotes.comments`. You would need to override the `get_context_data` method, and set `comments` on the `context_data` to accomplish what you are attempting to do there.

However, you don't need to do that at all, since you can get to the `comments` from the `ProjectNotes` object, and the `ProjectNotes` object is already in the `context`. Simply change your `for` loop to this:

```
{% for comment in projectnotes.comments %}
```

Comment: I had to change the for loop to `{% for comment in projectnotes.comments.all %}` to get it to work. Thank you for your help, Mark.